Capacitor Missing script: "start"
I have just created a capacitor project and I want to start it but I am getting the following error message:
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\my-app> npm run start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-27T08_41_01_552Z-debug.log

Here is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "capacitor-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An Amazing Capacitor App",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "capacitor",
    "mobile"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/core": "latest",
    "@capacitor/camera": "latest",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "latest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Notice that it is a fresh project. I have not changed anything yet.

The error message seems very clear. You only have one script: test.

Looks like you created the app with an old version of @capacitor/create-app
Use this command to make sure you are getting latest version npm init @capacitor/app@latest.
The @latest at the end makes it use latest version available.
Apps created with latest version have the start npm script, but previous versions didn’t have it.
